# What does "RDDs can be stored in memory" mean in Spark?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

In the introduction of Spark,it says

[RDDs can be stored in memory between queries without requiring replication](http://spark.apache.org/research.html).

As I know,you must cache RDD manually by using `.cache()` or `.persist()`.If I take neither measure,like below

```
   val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://data/kv1.txt")
   file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
   file.count()
```

I don't persist the RDD "file" in cache or disk,in this condition, can Spark run faster
than MapReduce?

Comment: If we have a Spark cluster with n GB of RAM and the file kv1.txt in the example above is several petabytes. Can Spark process it without calling persist() ?

Answer (score 4):

What will happen is that Spark will compute, partition by partition, each stage of the computation. It will hold some data temporarily in memory to do its work. It may have to spill data to disk and transfer across the network to execute some stages. But none of this is (necessarily) persistent. If you `count()` again it would start from scratch.

This is not a case where Spark would run faster than MapReduce; it would probably be *slower* for a simple operation like this. In fact, there is nothing about this that would benefit from loading into memory.

More complex examples, like with a non-trivial pipeline or repeated access to the RDD, would show a benefit from persisting in memory, or even on disk.

Comment: tks @Sean .You mentioned Spark"will hold some data temporarily in memory to do its work".So,memory is likely to be overflow when "temporary data" is large enough.How can I decide memory were able to fit the raw data's need?

Comment: No, not really. I'm referring to whatever memory your functions allocate, not that data consumes. Of course, it's always possible to make any program run out of memory by allocating a bunch of memory. I'm not sure what you're asking that's specific to Spark.

Answer (score 2):

Yes tonyking, it will run faster than MapReduce no doubt.
Spark processing all RDDs as in memory, each transformed RDD may be recomputed each time you run an action on it. However, you may also persist an RDD in memory using the persist (or cache) method, in which case Spark will keep the elements around on the cluster for much faster access the next time you query it. There is also support for persisting RDDs on disk, or replicated across multiple nodes.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

"This is very useful when data is accessed repeatedly, such as when querying a small “hot” dataset or when running an iterative algorithm like PageRank"

The answer for your question : "What does “RDDs can be stored in memory” mean in Spark?" is we can STORE one RDD in RAM using .cache() without re computation (while we are applying an action on it).

Comment: In this example, both would process "in memory" to the same degree. This is not a case where Spark is faster.

Comment: tks @Devan.I get that.But since Spark processes all RDDS in memory,the memory of cluster must be vary huge if we want to process TBs even PBs data!

Comment: Spark did n't take whole RDD at once, you can check the log, spark splits the files into chunks and process it.

Comment: @DevanMuthunayakanSreemandira so does MapReduce. This is not a difference.

Comment: Any operation that does a shuffle/reduce will naturally spill to disk in Hadoop. If that can be avoided, the computation will necessarily be faster