# Where do spark hold the RDD partitions

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I just need to know, where the spark actually put the RDD data partitions? If it is in-memory processing, does it partitioned the data inside the memory ?

(assuming that I have standalone spark , and working on Huge Text file , without hadoop cluster)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "RDDs can be stored in memory" mean in Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760206/what-does-rdds-can-be-stored-in-memory-mean-in-spark)

Comment: no actually my friend , i need to know about the partition place if i am not using cluster , like if i am using stand alone , lets say i am reading a huge text file into RDD , how spark will split it and where it will put the partitions ?